# docker not showing contents of mounted disk inside nfs storage

Tags: docker, mount, nfs, disk

I have nfs server where i am mounting a new disk. I can access disk contents from normal nfs client and its working as expected  but when i am mounting nfs volume inside docker it showing me all other contents except for mounted disk
this is image from mounted nfs volume inside docker

[image]
circled is the mounted disk on nfs server i can access its contents from nfs clients with out docker but with docker its empty

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps:

1. Change my local windows account password to something that does not have any special characters.
2. Turn off the windows firewall
3. Reset the credentials on all the shared drives and when entering the username prefix with the local computer name

Comment: but it on linux and i am trying to access from linux as well and with out docker its working fine